# jhipster and Spring 5 security for rest apis

Tags: spring, spring-security, jhipster

I'm new to jhipster and Spring 5. I've managed to create entities and can access those entities through the swagger apis and curl the data with the access tokens. I've also been able to add my own custom rest apis. What is not obvious is how to integrate my custom rest api into the same security framework that protects the data access apis related to the jhipster entity objects.

Any pointers on how to register my api with the jhipster/Spring security much appreciated!

Comment: Neither Spring 5 nor Spring Security 5 are yet released, so Jhipster does not support them. There's nothing special about JHipster in what you are trying to do, just read Spring Boot docs and tutorials.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Thanks for the advice. I've been reading through a book and some online docs but just haven't found what I'm looking for yet.

Comment: OK then your question is not precise enough and use wrong terms as there's nothing like a registration.